# Does deleting content on my phone affect content on Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, instant-upload

If I delete photos and videos on my device to make more space for other content on my device, will it delete the corresponding content backed up on Google Photos or will it stay online?

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct. Seems when I delete either way the photo is gone in both locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will stay online.
Auto-backup only add photo, they never remove it.

Comment: I would like a little more elaboration. Could you add a citation or a little more context?

Comment: I can confirm that deleting a photo from your Android device does not remove it from Google+ Auto Backup, and removing a photo from Google+ Auto Backup will not remove it from your Android device.

Comment: After I updated Google+ yesterday, I see this when I go to delete from the Photos app "Deleting will remove the photos and videos on your device and also any backups in your account", "Cancel"/"Delete everywhere"